# jQuery: How to select all divs specific class and append everything inside the div to a new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a style guide for a application.  I have several examples of different widgets.  I have wrapped each html block that I want to use as a snippet with the class "snippet".  I have a second empty div below each example widget with the class "example".  I am trying to use jQuery to select all the html blocks with the code snippet, grab everything inside the div and insert it inside the empty div (wrapped in pre and code tags).

Please see below for example:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="snippet panel-body">
        <h1>H1 Header Example</h1>
        <h2>H2 Header Example</h2>
        <h3>H3 Header Example</h3>
        <h4>H4 Header Example</h4>
        <p>
            Here is a p tag with a <a href="#">Link</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="example">
</div>
```

Comment: Does each `.snippet` element have `.example` element following ? Is requirement to append all `.snippet` elements `html` to single `.example` element ? , or for each `.snippet` element append that elements `html` to corresponding, following `.example` element ?

Comment: Try using [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) in place of [`[0]`](http://api.jquery.com/get/). The former returns a `jQuery` collection, which will have a [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method, containing the single `Element`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> have a second empty div below each example widget with the class
>   "example". I am trying to use jQuery to select all the html blocks
>   with the code snippet, grab everything inside the div and insert it
>   inside the empty div (wrapped in pre and code tags).

If interpret Question correctly , try using `.each()` , `.innerHTML` , `textarea` element

```js
$(".example").each(function(i, el) {
  el.innerHTML = "<textarea style=width:400px;height:200px>" 
                 + $(".snippet")[i].innerHTML 
                 + "</textarea>"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="snippet panel-body">
    <h1>H1 Header Example</h1>
    <h2>H2 Header Example</h2>
    <h3>H3 Header Example</h3>
    <h4>H4 Header Example</h4>
    <p>
      Here is a p tag with a <a href="#">Link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="example">
</div>
```

---

If rendered `html` is not to be edited , could add `disabled` attribute to string which renders `textarea` element

```js
$(".example").each(function(i, el) {
  el.innerHTML = "<textarea style=width:400px;height:200px disabled=true>" 
                 + $(".snippet")[i].outerHTML
                 + "</textarea>"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="snippet panel-body">
    <h1>H1 Header Example</h1>
    <h2>H2 Header Example</h2>
    <h3>H3 Header Example</h3>
    <h4>H4 Header Example</h4>
    <p>
      Here is a p tag with a <a href="#">Link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="example">
</div>
```

Comment: Why `textarea` instead of `<pre><code>` as mentioned in the question?

Comment: @JamesMontagne Not entirely certain , though appear OP attempting to render actual `html` markup ? `pre` , `code` could probably be substituted for `textarea`

Comment: Yeah, I agree you got the intent right.  Was just curious.  Textarea allows editing which probably isn't intended.

Comment: @JamesMontagne  _"Textarea allows editing which probably isn't intended. "_ Could add `disabled` attribute to `textarea` , see updated post

Comment: If editing isn't required, it'd be best to leave textarea all together and use code/pre elements - it's what they are intended for.

Comment: @BramVanroy _"If editing isn't required, it'd be best to leave textarea all together and use code/pre elements - it's what they are intended for."_ "Editing" text not appear at Question . Perhaps OP will chime in

Comment: Editing is not required - this was the closest answer and an easy fix to move from textarea to pre and code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because [0] returns the plain Dom object not a jquery one.

```
$('.snippet').each(function(i, item){ 
   $(item).next().text($(item).html());
  }
);
```

Comment: Typing on phone takes me a while ;)

Comment: But where is the display div in this answer?

Comment: I think the intent is to see the code (hence the pre and code elements).  So you would want `$(item).next().text($(item).html());`

Comment: Updated with your suggestion

Comment: Also, your `next` won't return anything as `.snippet` and `.example` are not siblings and you aren't adding the `<pre>` or `<code>`.

Comment: Napkin code sorry. See the other answers for a copy paste if that's what you are looking for

Comment: @JoshHarrison _"See the other answers for a copy paste if that's what you are looking for"_ "copy paste" of ?

Comment: ...Of a complete 0 effort  solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('.example').html($('.snippet').html());`

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```js
$(".example").append("<pre><code/></pre>");
$(".example code").html($(".snippet").html().replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="snippet panel-body">
    <h1>H1 Header Example</h1>
    <h2>H2 Header Example</h2>
    <h3>H3 Header Example</h3>
    <h4>H4 Header Example</h4>
    <p>
      Here is a p tag with a <a href="#">Link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="example">
</div>
```

---

More elaborately, you could make this more dynamic: generate `.example` after each snippet and fill it with the code from the preceding snippet.

```js
$(".snippet").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    ex = $("<div></div>").addClass("example").html(function() {
      return "<pre><code>" + $this.html().replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;") + "</pre></code>";
    });
  $this.parent("div").after(ex);
});
```

```css
.example {
  background: #ccc;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
}

.example pre {padding: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="snippet panel-body">
    <h1>H1 Header Example</h1>
    <h2>H2 Header Example</h2>
    <h3>H3 Header Example</h3>
    <h4>H4 Header Example</h4>
    <p>
      Here is a p tag with a <a href="#">Link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="snippet panel-body">
    <h1>H1 Another Header Example</h1>
    <h2>H2 Something similarHeader Example</h2>
    <h3>H3 Bananas Header Example</h3>
    <p>
      Here is a p tag with a <a href="#">Link</a> and guess what, even a
      <textarea disabled>I like turtles</textarea>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was a helpful answer.  I'm using codemirror so replacing the "<" and ">" wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your html file add this link

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

And at the bottom at this code to copy the div content and put it in ".example" div

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {  
     $('.example').html($('.snippet').clone()); 
    //$('.panel  .snippet').remove(); // use this portion to remove the previous div
   });
</script>
```